# UICollection Add borders to the inside part

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm looking how I can accomplish this task.

```
 X X X X
 X X X X
 X X X X
```

I need to set up borders like this

```
 X | X | X | X
 -   -   -   -
 X | X | X | X
 -   -   -   -
 X | X | X | X
```

How can be done this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might want to add vertical and horizontal 1 point view in the cell itself

Comment: Well I would prefer to add it between the two cells, because if the view is greater than my cells the UICollection have more space between them

Comment: I can't imagine how the it should looks like, but I think it will still valid, unless each cell has a different size...